# Angular 12 - Iterate Childrens HTMLElement of a given HTMLElement

Tags: angular, foreach

Maybe I've search the wrong way (I am totally new to Angular) but I would be happy to have a sample on how to iterate all the HTMLElements inside another HTMLElemnt. let's say I have this HTML:

```
<div id="modelpreview" class="previewbox">
    <img class="previewimg" src="../images/xxx1.png" id="prev1"</img>
    <img class="previewimg" src="../images/xxx2.png" id="prev2"</img>
    <img class="previewimg" src="../images/xxx3.png" id="prev3"</img>
</div>
```

I want to change the left/top position of every "img" inside "modelpreview" when resizing the browser window. thank you.

Comment: How exactly do you want them to behave? Are you sure you can't do it with css?

Comment: If you are manipulating DOM elements inside an Angular app, you're probably thinking about the problem wrong (are you coming from a jQuery background?). CSS is the best way to handle this. If it absolutely can't be done with CSS, just use standard JS: `document.getElementsByClassName('previewimg').forEach( ...manipulate... )`

Comment: I need to resize the internal "pieces" because they all together compose an image. so when the "main" landscape is resized I need to resize (and move) the internal pieces.